# Matlab: Storing an array in a matrix within a for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix

I'm running a for loop which outputs a (100x2) array which is called `AFdata`. For every loop iteration, I want to save `AFdata` in `AFmat`. However I cannot solve the algorithm to for the columns so that every `AFdata` of every iteration fills the right spot in `AFmat`.

This is code I am using now:

```
for i = 1:Nsections
    AFdata = Airfoil.getDatFile(Input.airfoilList{i},airfoilDir);
    if isfield(Input,'TcRatios') && ~isempty(Input.TcRatios)
        AFdata(:,2) = AFdata(:,2)*(Input.TcRatios(i)...
            /Airfoil.calculateThickness(AFdata(:,2)));
    end
end
```

for example:

the first iteration gives `AFdata = [1 0; 2 0; 3 0]`
the second iteration gives `AFdata = [4 9; 6 9; 8 9]`

and thus after 2 iterations, `AFmat` should be `[1 0 4 9; 2 0 6 9 ;3 0 8 9]`

thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-allocate `AFmat` with required size first and then fill appropriate columns at each iteration, e.g.

```
AFmat = zeros(100, 2*Nsections);
for i = 1:Nsections
    % ... calc AFdata
    AFmat(:,[2*i-1,2*i]) = AFdata;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cat()` function. Declare `AFmat` as a blank matrix (if you don't know the exact dimension) and just concatenate afterwards.

```
    AFmat=[];
    for i = 1:Nsections
    %calculate AFdata...............
    AFmat=cat(2,AFmat,AFdata);
    end
```

I've heard comments that this affects the code performance (not allocating the matrix) but MATLAB doesn't complain. I personally like this because the dimension in the `cat()` function feels easy to me to control the final matrix property.